# Setup failed in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUMuu.jpg)

I keep repairing, reinstall, delete etc. But still this failed keep showing. I dont know why. My first time installing visual studio 2015, I can running like usual. After I shut down my pc and open it back. This things happen. Help me.

Comment: Could you post the log file?

Comment: I didnt get it. What do you means?

Answer (score -1):

whats the error u get, and am advising u to go back to  visual studio 2012 as i love it and to me is the best because the requirement is not mch as of that 2015